# how to Set default value for author field in django form using views.py

Tags: python, mysql, django, templates, frontend

Im developing a social website I have problem in creating new post I don't know how set author name as default of logged in user it always give option for all the previously logged in users  I want to make it default for the logged in user I don't know how to set default value for that author field

views.py

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
login_url = '/login/'
redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
form_class = PostForm
model = Post
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):


class Meta():
    model = Post

    fields = ('author','title','text','Post_image')
    widgets = {
        'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
        'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent '})

    }
```

modesls.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    Post_image= models.ImageField(upload_to='media' ,blank=True ,editable=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try define get_initial.

```
def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = super(CreatePostView, self).get_initial(**kwargs)
        initial['author'] = 'default author'
        return initial
```

Comment: could you share your template?

Comment: i have multiple templates which you want

Comment: https://dpaste.org/3vhK
thats the template where im creating my post and where i have to select author which i wanted to be default